# Vue.js: Using a dynamically created v-model with v-for loop and v-if to show/hide elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue to display an accordion (using foundation CSS framework for the accordion). I use `v-for` to loop through the data, and build the accordion. Inside the accordion, I will have four radio buttons. If the user clicks on a specific one (say, `job 3`), I need to display an input box under the radio buttons.

```
<dd class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(job, index) in jobs">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job1">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job2">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job3">

  <!-- The input box below should only be displayed if job 3 is selected. -->
  <input type="text" v-bind:id="find-user-' + job.id">
</dd>
```

I'm having a bit of trouble conceptualizing how to execute this.

I was thinking that I could create a v-model on all of the radio buttons, sorta dynamically create it I guess, and then reference it in the input with a `v-if`. But my page isn't rendering when I try to do this. This is what I tried below.

```
<dd class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(job, index) in jobs">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job1" v-model="jobNumber + job.id">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job2" v-model="jobNumber + job.id">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job3" v-model="jobNumber + job.id">

  <!-- The input box below should only be displayed if job 3 is selected. -->
  <template v-if="jobNumber + job.id == 'job3'">
    <input type="text" v-bind:id="find-user-' + job.id">
  </template>
</dd>
```

I even tried surrounding `jobNumber` with single quotes with no luck.

Am I even on the right track? How would I get this to work?

Comment: template has to be the parent Tag

Comment: I expect what you want is some sort of `selectedJob` for each `job` object and that is what your `v-model` would bind to. Like this: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BJoymR?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert Adding another key-value pair to my objects is exactly what I needed! Definitely overthought this. You should submit your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is often solved by adding a property to each of the object you are iterating over.

In this example, I added the `selected` property to each job object.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    jobs:[
      {id: 1, selected: null},
      {id: 2, selected: null},
      {id: 3, selected: null},
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dd class="accordion-navigation" v-for="(job, index) in jobs">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job1" v-model="job.selected">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job2" v-model="job.selected">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'job-radio-' + job.id" value="job3" v-model="job.selected">

    <!-- The input box below should only be displayed if job 3 is selected. -->
    <template v-if="job.selected === 'job3'">
      <br>
      <input type="text" v-bind:id="'find-user-' + job.id">
    </template>
  </dd>
</div>
```

You can see if you select the third radio button in each job iteration, the input will appear.